# Windows 10 - Screen won't wake up

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, asus

Does anybody have the same issue? Usually, after my laptop sleeps, or let's say the screen turned off after 5 minutes of idle I just move my mouse or press any key from my keyboard then the screen goes up then I can continue working.

It's been a week of having this issue, I'm not sure what just happened. I'm pretty sure it is working because there was a sound of error when I press any key on my keyboard, it's just the monitor won't wake up.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

**Asus X441N**, running on **Windows 10 version 20H2** with **SSD**.

Currently, to avoid the issue, I set the `Screen` and `Sleep` to `Never`.

Comment: Please kindly check if methods in this article was helpful: [Computer monitor won’t wake up from sleep](https://windowsreport.com/computer-wont-wake-up-from-sleep/#:~:text=6.-,Check%20your%20Power%20Management%20settings,devices%20to%20wake%20the%20computer.&text=Make%20sure%20the%20option%20Allow,wake%20the%20computer%20is%20checked.)

Comment: @Sunny - I think PowerManagement is available only for external Keyboard and Mouse. I see no option in mine, I'm using a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is something relative to the display driver. You have two options to solve this issue.

- First one, as you said to avoid the issue you will need to go in `Power & Sleep Settings` and set the `Screen` and `Sleep` to `Never` then
  you can wait for the next Windows Update or check for the display
  driver update every week and see if it solves the issue.
- The second one is to roll back from the previous version of the
  display driver and see if it solves the issue.